# Issue with One Way Binding Using Knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, observable

I'm currently using Knockoutjs in one of my projects. I'm trying to do one-way binding in my HTML to a span tag but I'm not having any luck. I'm getting my data from an ajax call and I can see my property PersonName being populated with the returned value in the browser devloper tools; however, my UI isn't showing that value. If I make the property an observable then it shows. I have the following code:

```
function MyObjectModel() {
var self = this;

self.PersonName = "";
self.Instructions = "";
self.HasDetails = false;

self.isLoaded = ko.observable(false);
self.loadingMessage = ko.observable("");

function init() {
    $.ajax({
        url: <url to api>,
        type: 'GET',
        beforeSend: () => {
            ... 
    })
        .done((data) => {
            if (!account.handleInvalidSessionResponse(data, true)) {
                self.PersonName = data.PersonName;
                self.Instructions = data.Instructions;
                self.HasDetails = data.HasDetails;
            }
        })
        .catch((jqXHR, errorThrown, textStatus) => {
            ...
        })
        .always(() => {
            ...
        })
}
init();
```

}

```
$(function () {
var viewModel = new MyObjectModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, document.querySelector("[main-myObjectDetail]"));
```

});

My UI has this tag

```
<span data-bind="text: PersonName"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your UI isn't showing the value because `PersonName` isn't an observable. So you need to make it that.